# WSO2: Dashboard can't access published event data from CEP

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-cep

I've installed CEP and Dashboard Server (WSO2) yesterday on my Mac. My problem is, that my dashboard does not get the data of the events i simulated. I can create the gadgets and also see which attributes are defined in the data stream, but when i want to view the dashboard there is only this message:

> "No events published. Publish events to see a preview of the selected
>   chart."

Also i can see the results when using a logger as publisher, so the execution plan has to work.

Hope you have any ideas how to solve this. Thanks Joe

Comment: What version of the WSO2 CEP are you using? Are you testing with the Analytics Dashboard that's embedded with the WSO2 CEP? Did you create UI publisher to the stream that you need to present in the Dashboard ?

Comment: I am using CEP-4.1.0 and dashboard version 2.0.0. I was testing both. First the embedded dashboard from cep then the other. I created a publisher, also the dashboard recognize the publisher, so that it could use the attributes of the output stream for creating a gadget. But when i was simulating a data stream, the gadgets didn't receive the data.

But I tried the same event on a windows vm and everything worked pretty well. So I'm about to continue my work on the vm, even if it's a bit more complicated.